# Как реализовать такой автокомплит?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, autocomplete

Есть [вот такой вот](https://www.onliner.by/) сайт у него в поиске интересный автокомплит, подскажите как можно реализовать такой же или подобный? Возможно есть какие нибудь плагины/готовые решения для этого. Или это самописный вариант, и без программирования тут не обойтись?

Comment: я бы не стал это автокомплитом назыать. это поиск икрементальный. скорее всего это самописное. в общем то сложного ничего нет.  результаты поиска по ключевому слову подгружаются аяксом и вам отображаются. в целом типовая задача в своем дизайне.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько знаю, готовых решений такого плана нет. Придется писать, благо это не особо сложная задача. Принцип такой - создаем поле, создаем скрытый блок для вывода результатов. Далее на событие **onkeyup** к примеру, вешаем запрос к серверу, передаем туда уже набранный текст из нашего поля. Сервер же ищет в БД совпадения, ссылки на изображения и прочее и отдает нам JSON с упорядоченными данными. На стороне клиента разбираем и расставляем так, как нам удобно